# How do I get my table to scroll, while the background stays fixed in html/css?

Tags: html, css, scroll, scrollbar

I have a personal webpage where all my content is loaded into a table with a set background color centered mid-page, while the actual background is an image.  There's enough content in the table that I cannot fit it all in the window view without scrolling, but my scroll bar does not show up.  I want to scroll down the the page, but it won't let me.  I tried extending the height of my document in the html tag, but that just scrolls the background image down, it doesn't scroll the table down.  Any suggestions?

Everywhere I go, there's always some suggestions about setting the style to overflow:auto or some such setting, but that never works. Here's the HTML and CSS

```
<body style="background-image:url(assets/images/bckg1.jpg); background-     
position:center; background-repeat:repeat;">
<br />
<div style="overflow:auto; position:fixed; display:block;">
<table id="scrollable-table" class="main-content" border="3" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20">`

html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }
body { 
    overflow:hidden; 
    font: 75% georgia, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.88889;
    color: #555753; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    }
.main-content {
    position: fixed;
    left:25%;
    right:25%;
    width:50%;
    background: #D2F0FF;
    border-left:groove;
    border-right:groove;
    border-color:#0066FF;
}

#scrollable-table, tbody{
    display:block;
    overflow-y:auto;
/*  position:fixed;*/
}
```

Is there an easy solution?  Perhaps a js or jquery solution?

Comment: *Is there an easy solution?* Yes, [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables).

Answer (score 0):

If you will add "height" to #scrollable-table - you'll be able to scroll.

```
#scrollable-table, tbody{
    height: 100%;
    display:block;
    overflow-y:auto;
    /*  position:fixed;  */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pk4s7tss/2/